# Oracle converting a working query to a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, grouping

I have a test case below, which is working fine. In the first scenario I am repeating using TRUC(access_date) so the grouping will work properly.

I want to use a subquery only once to do the TRUNC(access_date) to make the code more legible and only do the TRUNC command in one place but I am having difficulty making it work.

Can someone show me how to resolve this issue. I provided the working version and my attempt, which I couldn't work.

```
 ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS';

    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE nt_date IS TABLE OF DATE;
    /

    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_dates_pipelined(
     p_from IN DATE,
     p_to   IN DATE
   )
   RETURN nt_date  PIPELINED     DETERMINISTIC
   IS
      v_start DATE := TRUNC(LEAST(p_from, p_to));
     v_end   DATE := TRUNC(GREATEST(p_from, p_to));
    BEGIN
    LOOP
        PIPE ROW (v_start);
        EXIT WHEN v_start >= v_end;
        v_start := v_start + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
      END LOOP;
      RETURN;
    END  generate_dates_pipelined;
    /

    create table employees(
      employee_id NUMBER(6), 
      first_name VARCHAR2(20),
     last_name VARCHAR2(20),
     card_num VARCHAR2(10),
     work_days VARCHAR2(7)
    );

   ALTER TABLE employees
  ADD (
     CONSTRAINT employees_pk PRIMARY KEY (employee_id)
  );

   INSERT INTO employees (
     EMPLOYEE_ID,
     first_name, 
     last_name,
     card_num,
    work_days
   )
   WITH names AS ( 
     SELECT 1, 'Jane',     'Doe',      'F123456', 'NYYYYYN'   FROM dual UNION ALL 
      SELECT 2, 'Madison', 'Smith', 'R33432','NYYYYYN' FROM dual UNION ALL 
      SELECT 3, 'Justin',   'Case',     'C765341','NYYYYYN' FROM dual UNION ALL 
     SELECT 4, 'Mike',     'Jones',      'D564311','NYYYYYN' FROM dual  )
   SELECT * FROM names;  

   CREATE TABLE locations AS
     SELECT level AS location_id,
      'Door ' || level AS location_name,
      CASE round(dbms_random.value(1,3)) 
          WHEN 1 THEN 'A' 
          WHEN 2 THEN 'T' 
          WHEN 3 THEN 'T' 
      END AS location_type
    FROM   dual
    CONNECT BY level <= 3;


   ALTER TABLE locations 
     ADD ( CONSTRAINT locations_pk
     PRIMARY KEY (location_id));

    create table access_history(     
       seq_num integer  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
      employee_id NUMBER(6), 
      card_num varchar2(10),
      location_id number(4),
       access_date date,
       processed NUMBER(1) default 0
   );

   create or replace procedure create_access_history(p_start_date date, p_end_date date)
    IS
    
    BEGIN
    INSERT into    access_history
     (
      employee_id,
      card_num,
       location_id, 
       access_date
     )
             WITH  cntr  AS
    (
 SELECT LEVEL - 1 AS n
  FROM     dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 15 -- Max number of rows per employee per date
    )
    ,            got_location_num  AS
    (
SELECT  location_id
,    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY location_id) AS location_num
,    COUNT (*)   OVER ()            AS max_location_num
FROM     locations
    )
   ,    employee_days  AS
    (
    SELECT         e.employee_id, e.card_num
,      d.column_value         AS access_date
,          dbms_random.value (0, 15) AS rn    -- 0 to max number of rows per employee per date
    FROM     employees e
      CROSS JOIN TABLE (generate_dates_pipelined (p_start_date, p_end_date)) d
       )
   ,               employee_n_days  AS
   (
       SELECT        ed.employee_id, ed.card_num, ed.access_date
,     dbms_random.value (0, 1) AS lrn
    FROM     employee_days        ed
     JOIN    cntr            c  ON  c.n <= ed.rn
  )
      SELECT       n.employee_id,       n.card_num, l.location_id, 
      n.access_date +                            NUMTODSINTERVAL(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0,86399)), 'SECOND') 
      FROM     employee_n_days  n
    JOIN         got_location_num  l  ON l.location_num = CEIL (n.lrn * l.max_location_num); 
   END;

      EXEC  create_access_history (DATE '2021-08-06',  DATE '2021-08-11');

    -- Works 
    select TRUNC(a. access_date) access_date,
   e.employee_id, 
   count(*) cnt         
    FROM  employees    e
    JOIN  access_history a ON a.employee_id = e.employee_id
    JOIN  locations     l ON l.location_id = a.location_id
    GROUP BY  GROUPING SETS (
    (TRUNC(a.access_date), e.employee_id),       
   (trunc(a.access_date)),
     ()
   )
   ORDER BY trunc(a. access_date),e.employee_id;
```

Fixed

select
access_date,
employee_id,
count(*)
FROM
(
select TRUNC(a.access_date) as access_date,
e.employee_id
FROM  employees    e
JOIN     access_history a ON a.employee_id = e.employee_id

JOIN  locations     l ON l.location_id = a.location_id           )  ah_trunc
GROUP BY  GROUPING SETS (
(access_date,  employee_id),
(access_date),
()
)
ORDER BY  access_date,employee_id;

Comment: I didn't follow the whole thing, but in your final query, ah_trunc has two columns named `"TRUNC(a.access_date)"` and `employee_id`, which is why you can't select `access_date` from it (if that's what "doesn't work" means). Try giving the first one an alias.

Comment: OK, so your original example works if you fix the typo (stray dot after `JOIN  locations l.`) and alias `TRUNC(a.access_date)` as I suggested. I'm not sure you needed 150 lines of code to demo that.

Answer (score 0):

If I read this correctly, it looks like the issue can be simplified to the following.

Why does this query fail with "invalid identifier"?

```
select dummy
from   ( select lower(dummy) from dual );
```

```
ERROR at line 1:  
ORA-00904: "DUMMY": invalid identifier
```

It's because the inline view only has a column named `"LOWER(DUMMY)"`. You either need to refer to that (complete with double quotes), or else give it a name:

```
select dummy
from   ( select lower(dummy) as dummy from dual );
```

```
DUMMY
------
x

1 row selected.
```

Comment: I tried the following in the subqery and it didn't work select TRUNC(a.access_date) as access_date,
...  something else appears to be the issue or I misunderstood your response. Any other suggestions? Thanks for responding

Comment: When I tried the alias I get the following error ORA-00905: missing keyword.  If you run my test CASE you can see the issue